# How to remove wordpress entirely from my domain name that's hosted on AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wordpress, website, domain-name

I was contacted by an organization to remove wordpress site that's host on Amazon Web Services(AWS) route53,the site is running with an associated EC2 instance, that was created all created by the developer who left the organization, After spending sleepless hours of doing technical research, am a little bit worried, should I delete the instance that's associated with the site, because I want to deploy a new site onto the same domain that's being used the wordpress site?

Any guideline will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It depends. Is anything else running on that instance? Do they need the domain to keep working or do they want the domain shut down? Route53 records might give you a clue. If you do anything with the instance STOP it rather than terminating it, and take an instance snapshot before you do anything. Maybe this job should go to someone who understands AWS.

Comment: @Tim ,I have developed a new site that's running on my local machine, so I want to upload it to the same domain name. There's nothing else running on the instance apart from the wordpress site that's running on the domain

Comment: Based on what you've said I think you need to engage with an AWS infrastructure expert to help you and ensure things are secured. But if you want to risk it you have two options 1) SSH into the instance, set up the new website, and then switch the web server config to point to it 2) (Better) Set up a new EC2 instance, get it working, then change R53 DNS to point to it.

Comment: The second option would be better, I think it will also help me not to cause interference.

Comment: Rephrasing the question would make it easier to follow. 

From what I can gather you don't need anything from the old site. So snapshot or create an AMI from the currently running instance and shut it down.

Create a new instance, deploy the new site and then update the DNS (route 53) to point to the new IP.
Make sure you harden the new instance